# Rename-Item fails when there are brackets (regex/escaping issue)

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am simply trying to rename files using PowerShell, but the script below does not work when there are brackets:

```
$old = [regex] '_Jackson\(UK\)_'
$new = [regex] '_Jackson\(US\)_'
get-childitem "K:\CustomerVideos" -include @("*.webm","*.mp4","*.mkv") -recurse | foreach-object { rename-item $_ -newname ( $_.name -creplace $old,$new ) }
```

*Rename-Item : Cannot rename because the target specified represents a path or device name.*

It does work when $old and $new do NOT contain brackets so I guess it's an escaping issue, yet I'm already using backslashes… what is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the escaping in the second string?

Comment: @NathanTuggy It works! But… why? Aren't both supposed to be regex?

Comment: I had an intuition something was fishy, and I've done some more experimentation and come up with the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because regex *replacement* syntax is greatly simplified (character classes, grouping, backreferences, and so forth are all disabled, because they're only good when *matching*), including the backslashes only confuses things. Specifically, it leaves both backslash and "escaped" character in the final string. This is because `[regex]` objects are not actually usable as the replacement strings, so they have to be auto-converted to strings by way of `ToString()` first, which returns the original pattern.

Only ever use strings for the replacement patterns.

Comment: I don't understand. When I use (unnamed) capture groups, the replacement does work like a regex, eg. ``$old = [regex] "_(Jackson)(Steve)\(UK\)_"`` ``$new = [regex] "_`$2`$1(UK)_"`` turns \_JacksonSteve(UK)\_ into \_SteveJackson(UK)\_ . Is there a reference page where I can see what regex functions work in PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: `$2` is not regex syntax, and means nothing within a regex. It's regex *replacement string* syntax. The `[regex]` in that example is equally redundant, and for the same reason as I gave earlier; it's just getting interpreted as a string with a pair of substitutions, which are *not* the same as backreferences in an actual regex pattern. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx#alert_note) has the details for all .NET regex operations, including PowerShell; PowerShell regex behavior has not changed significantly with its versions.